# Cannot switch gem versions in an rbenv environment

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew, rbenv

I have rbenv 1.1.2 installed via Homebrew on my macOS 10.14.4.

I am having trouble running gems at a version different from the latest available.

For example, I have three versions of the xcodeproj gem installed (1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.5.7).

If I run `xcodeproj --version`, I see 1.8.2, as expected.

However, if I run `xcodeproj _1.5.7_ --version`, I also see 1.8.2, while expecting 1.5.7.

Note that passing the version does something - if I pass an invalid version (e.g. *1.5.0*), I do get the "can't find gem xcodeproj (= 1.5.0)" error as expected.

What can I do to be able to run previous versions?

Comment: what about a gemfile? you can specify specific versions there. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: Like @MrRoth said in their answer, I could use a Gemfile and bundler, but this will, as far as I understand, to use bundler everywhere I want to use the gem. While it would make sense for Rails, it makes less sense for command-line tools such as CococaPods which I use.

I guess the real question is if this is a bug with rbenv in particular. When gems are installed via rbenv, they are stubbed in ls ~/.rbenv/shims and execute via /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/rbenv. Does it mean that rbenv does not properly understand the _version_ directive?

Comment: rbenv will resolve to ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/xcodeproj which contains the following line:

load Gem.bin_path('xcodeproj', 'xcodeproj', version)

The version does get passed in correctly, so running "xcodeproj _1.5.7_ --version" results in Gem.bin_path() returning "~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/bin/xcodeproj". What's unclear is why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [bundler](https://bundler.io/) to mange the rubygems dependencies specified in a Gemfile. for instance:

```
$ cat Gemfile
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "xcodeproj", "1.5.7"
```

install them using bundler

```
$ bundle install --path gems
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...............
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching CFPropertyList 3.0.0
Installing CFPropertyList 3.0.0
Fetching atomos 0.1.3
Installing atomos 0.1.3
Using bundler 1.17.2
Fetching claide 1.0.2
Installing claide 1.0.2
Fetching colored2 3.1.2
Installing colored2 3.1.2
Fetching nanaimo 0.2.6
Installing nanaimo 0.2.6
Fetching xcodeproj 1.5.7
Installing xcodeproj 1.5.7
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 7 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./gems`
```

then execute your rubygem using bundler

```
$ bundle exec xcodeproj --version
1.5.7
```

note that when you are using rbenv and would like to execute a rubygem without bundler management, then you will have to make sure that for each rbenv version, you install your favorite gems. for instance, if you are using 2 different ruby versions and you like pry rubygem, then you will have to install pry for each ruby version.

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, it is fairly heavy-handed - I use many gems as command-line tools (most commonly CocoaPods) and if I understand correctly, I need to be in the context of the "current bundle" to run bundle exec, meaning that I need to create a Gemfile in every directory I want to run the tool in.

For example, I uses CocoaPods to fetch libraries for Xcode projects. Normally, all I need is a Podfile in each Xcode project directory. With the bundler approach, I would also need a Gemfile for each Xcode project as well. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @DavidAirapetyan: firstly, if that solves the issue on your post, please accept my answer. for your other question, in theory you are correct although it can be "hacked". i also updated my answer.

Comment: It doesn't quite solve my problem, but I suppose it does answer the question as it was stated. It feels like I am running into a limitation/bug of rbenv - there is evidence what I am trying to do actually works with RVM.